# How can I delete an all records matched?

Tags: airflow

I have the code like:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
d = func.date('2021-6-23')
session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= d).delete()
```

feedback is :

```
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3926, in delete
delete_op.exec_()
```

I have tried:

```
session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= d).all()
```

it worked.

I cannot find out a reference for this. Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in  [sqlalchemy page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete)

just add `synchronize_session=False` inside `delete()`

```
session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= d).delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: Does anyone have another approach for this ?